# JQuery find() element that's in the same div as the element that fired the event

Tags: jquery, html

I have this HTML for a contact request system:

```
<div class="request">
    <img src=" static/img/user/personalProfilePicture/mod_50_50/f31e80de993a4eff4561d5368fe0a7792c2cbfde.jpg " alt=" Hakan" class="requestPic" />
    <a href="#" class="requestName">Hakan Simsir</a>
    <!--<a href="../scrapll_m_nonstatic/process/cont/accept.php?uid1=68&uid2=66 " class="acceptRequest"></a>-->
    <button class="acceptRequest"></button>
    <div class="requestUnderline"></div>
    <div class="profilesList">
        <ul class="profilesListUl">
            <li class="profilesListLi">
                <span style="font: 15px sans-serif, arial; color: #777;">Add this person to a profile</span>
            </li>
            <li class="profilesListLi">
                <a href="../scrapll_m_nonstatic/process/cont/accept.php?uid1=68&uid2=66&p_id=1" class="profilesListA">Family</a>
            </li>
            <li class="profilesListLi">
                <a href="../scrapll_m_nonstatic/process/cont/accept.php?uid1=68&uid2=66&p_id=2" class="profilesListA">Friends</a>
            </li>
            <li class="profilesListLi">
                <a href="../scrapll_m_nonstatic/process/cont/accept.php?uid1=68&uid2=66&p_id=3" class="profilesListA">Work</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="request">
    <img src=" static/img/user/personalProfilePicture/mod_50_50/f31e80de993a4eff4561d5368fe0a7792c2cbfde.jpg " alt=" Hakan" class="requestPic" />
    <a href="#" class="requestName">Hakan Simsir</a>
    <!--<a href="../scrapll_m_nonstatic/process/cont/accept.php?uid1=68&uid2=66 " class="acceptRequest"></a>-->
    <button class="acceptRequest"></button>
    <div class="requestUnderline"></div>
    <div class="profilesList">
        <ul class="profilesListUl">
            <li class="profilesListLi">
                <span style="font: 15px sans-serif, arial; color: #777;">Add this person to a profile</span>
            </li>
            <li class="profilesListLi">
                <a href="../scrapll_m_nonstatic/process/cont/accept.php?uid1=68&uid2=66&p_id=1" class="profilesListA">Family</a>
            </li>
            <li class="profilesListLi">
                <a href="../scrapll_m_nonstatic/process/cont/accept.php?uid1=68&uid2=66&p_id=2" class="profilesListA">Friends</a>
            </li>
            <li class="profilesListLi">
                <a href="../scrapll_m_nonstatic/process/cont/accept.php?uid1=68&uid2=66&p_id=3" class="profilesListA">Work</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

These are two elements of the class '.request'. In each request element there is a button element with the classname 'acceptRequest'. When the .acceptRequest button is clicked, the element with classname '.profilesList' should appear (it's got display none by default). However, every .request element has the element profilesList dedicated to it, so when the acceptRequest button of the first .request element is clicked, the profilesList element of the first .request element has to appear, when the acceptButton of the second .request element is clicked, the profilesList of the second request should appear etc.

I've used JQuery find() to achieve this:

```
$(".acceptRequest").click(function(){
    $(".request").find(".profilesList").css( "display", "block" )
});
```

This code, however, affects the profilesList element of both request elements, but I only need to see the one I clicked for.

Can anyone help me out with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `closest()` to find the closest parent  `.request`, then find anything in that etc.

```
$(".acceptRequest").click(function(){
    $(this).closest(".request").find(".profilesList").show();
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/5JUyG/)

Comment: @EhsanSajjad - Sure it will

Comment: you can try it in fiddle it will not

Comment: @EhsanSajjad - added a fiddle

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$(this)` to target current clicked `.acceptRequest` element along with **[.siblings()](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/)** since `.profilesList` is the sibling of your `.acceptRequest`:

> Get the siblings of each element in the set of matched elements,
>   optionally filtered by a selector.

```
$(".acceptRequest").click(function(){
    $(this).siblings('.profilesList').show();
});
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mBrW2/)**

Comment: Thx! Yours works too, I just used the code of the guy above because his answer was at the top. Thx to both of you guys!

Answer (score 0):

Looking at DOM structure, You can use `.parent()` along with `.find()` to get `.profilesList`:

```
$(".acceptRequest").click(function(){
    $(this).parent().find(".profilesList").show();
});
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/5JUyG/1/)**